# Sequence number in excel for non blank rows

Tags: excel, sequence

How to add sequence numbers in excel, wherein the sequence number starts based on the value of the column B. It should not add the sequence if there is no text in the corresponding row of Column B.
So the row 4 should start with 1 since the column B is having some value.

The example sheet is attached.
Also how can i auto update the sequence if i add new row to it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In A2, enter the following formula and copy down as required.

```
=IF(B2="","",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In A2

```
=COUNTA(B$2:B2)
```

and fill down

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the reply.
i get the required, but i can see the number in non blank rows with the previous row value.
How can i make the repeated number not to be visible?

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",COUNTA(B$2:B2))`

Comment: I believe you're right. I should have worked on a TRUE/FALSE based on the length of the value in column B as the OP has not definitively expressed that it could not be a formula returning a zero-length string.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Could you add your comment as an answer? It solved my problem when the others didn't, and answers really shouldn't be in comments in case they get deleted for whatever reason.